# List of columns meeting a certain condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Working with Python 3.7.9, Spark 2.4.5
I am trying to manually "try parse" a given subset of columns from string to integer, and then add two extra columns to the dataframe:

- _num_invalid_columns: with the number of columns that failed parsing (signaled as -9999)
- _invalid_colums_list: with a comma or pipe separated list of columns that failed parsing

I was able to calculate "_num_invalid_columns", but am having issues with "_invalid_columns_list".
Code to reproduce below, I reduced it as much as possible.

```
'''
Uncomment these 2 lines if using Jupyter Notebook
import findspark
findspark.init()
'''
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def tryparse_integer(integer_str):    
    '''
    if integer_str is None returns None as IntegerType()
    if integer_str is not None and cannot be parsed to integer, returns -9999 as IntegerType()
    if integer_str is not None and can be parsed to integer, returns integer_str as IntegerType()
    (that way we can tell between null data and invalid data)
    '''
    return F.when(F.isnull(integer_str), F.lit(None).cast(IntegerType())) \
        .otherwise( \
            F.when(F.isnull(integer_str.cast(IntegerType())), F.lit(-9999).cast(IntegerType())) \
            .otherwise(integer_str.cast(IntegerType())) \
        ) 
        
def is_invalid_number(col):
    return F.when(col == -9999, 1).otherwise(0)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("RandallTest").getOrCreate()

data = [('1', '2','hello'), ('error','error','hello'), ('error','2','hello')]

schema = StructType([
  StructField('column1', StringType()),
  StructField('column2', StringType()),
  StructField('column3', StringType())
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema = schema)

df.printSchema()

integerColumns = ['column1','column2']

df_parsed = df.select(*[
    tryparse_integer(F.col(colName)).alias(colName) if (colName in integerColumns)
    else colName
    for colName in df.columns])  

df_parsed.printSchema()

df_parsed_with_errorcount = df_parsed \
    .withColumn('_num_invalid_columns', sum(
    is_invalid_number(F.col(colName)) if (colName in integerColumns) 
    else 0
    for colName in df_parsed.columns)) \
    .withColumn('_invalid_columns_list', F.lit('--'.join(filter(None, (
    ##Not what I need, but works:
    colName if (colName in integerColumns)  
    ##Not working if I uncomment the actual logic I want. Something like any of these lines (59, 60 or 61 all produce errors)
    ##colName if (colName in integerColumns and F.col(colName) == -9999)
    ##colName if (colName in integerColumns & F.col(colName) == -9999)
    ##colName if (colName in integerColumns & is_invalid_number(F.col(colName)) == 1)
    else None
    for colName in df_parsed.columns)))))   

df_parsed_with_errorcount.show()
df_parsed_with_errorcount.take(10)
```

Example Input:

```
column1     column2     column3     
'1'         '2'         'hello'        
'error'     'error'     'hello'     
'error'     '2'         'hello'
```

Columns to "try parse": column1, column2

Expected output:

```
column1     column2     column3     _num_invalid_columns    _invalid_columns_list
1           2           'hello'     0   
-9999       -9999       'hello'     2                       column1,column2
-9999       2           'hello'     1                       column1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `F.lit(colName)` to put your column names into the dataframe:

```
df_parsed_with_errorcount = df_parsed.withColumn(
    '_invalid_columns_list',
    F.concat_ws(
        ',',
        *[F.when(is_invalid_number(F.col(colName)) == 1, F.lit(colName)) for colName in df_parsed.columns]
    )
)

df_parsed_with_errorcount.show()
+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
|column1|column2|column3|_invalid_columns_list|
+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
|      1|      2|  hello|                     |
|  -9999|  -9999|  hello|      column1,column2|
|  -9999|      2|  hello|              column1|
+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way around using F.when though, something similar to the "cased" for I used for "sum"? My real use case would have more than integer "try parses", my actual _num_invalid_columns for instance looks like this: df_parsed_with_errorcount = df_parsed.withColumn('_num_invalid_columns', sum(
    is_invalid_date(F.col(colName)) if (colName in dateColumns.keys())   
    else is_invalid_number(F.col(colName)) if (colName in list(set().union(decimal164Columns, decimal96Columns, decimal84Columns, integerColumns))) 
    else 0
    for colName in df_parsed.columns))

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon input from mck, my final code looks like this:

First a modification to the helper function to make it "type safe", so to speak

```
def is_invalid_number(col):
    ##return F.when(col == -9999, 1).otherwise(0) --> does not work, no type safety
    return F.when(col.cast(StringType()) == '-9999', 1).otherwise(0)
```

And then the actual column calculation using concat_ws() + array_contains() + my helper function

```
df_parsed_with_errorcount = df_parsed \
    .withColumn('_num_invalid_columns', sum(
    is_invalid_number(F.col(colName)) if (colName in integerColumns) 
    else 0
    for colName in df_parsed.columns)) \
    .withColumn('_invalid_columns_list', F.concat_ws(',', *[ \
    (F.when(F.array_contains(F.array([F.lit(x) for x in integerColumns]), colName), F.when(is_invalid_number(F.col(colName)) == 1, F.lit(colName))) \
    .otherwise(F.lit(None))
    ) for colName in df_parsed.columns]))
```

From what I can tell from the error messages shown before making the is_invalid_number helper function type safe ; Spark does *not* guarantee the order of execution of the conditions within the when(), even after nesting one when() function within another, as opposed to using one single when() function with two conditions separated by & (and)